# Deploy Biztalk project with TFS

Tags: tfs, biztalk, biztalk-2013, btdf

Is there any other options to deploy BizTalk projects with TFS other than Biztalk Deployment Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically yes, but practically not. BTDF is the only mature and live solution around that I am aware of.

Comment: hi can you tell me what the difference of BTDF, Team build, Team city. witch one is the fastest way do deploy a biztalk project?

Comment: Team Build usually refers to TFS Build features: you describe your build steps in workflow and setup the Controller/Agent infrastructure to run it. TeamCity is a product that allows to describe your build steps and run them on a network of Agents.
Both system are agnostic: you can build anything, they orchestrate resources for you.

BTDF is short for Biztalk Deployment Framework and is an MSBuild based tooling to deploy Biztalk artifacts; as such it can integrate with any Build infrastructure.

Comment: If you adopt BTDF, instead of writing your deploy script from scratch, or using a fragile manual process, you must follow its patterns: the build produces an MSI, install the MSI on the target machine then run BTDF to deploy.